# How can I see cards in archived boards?

Tags: trello

I want to look at the cards associated with a closed Board so I can make sure I have the correct cards on my new Board. I don't want to copy the Board, as the cards associated with the Archived board are not necessarily appropriate for the new Board. When I reopen the Archived board, my cards are empty. I can see the cards in the Activity list, but I'd really like to see the detail on the boards.

Also, is it possible to view the Archived board without reopening them?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can only view open boards, so you'd need to re-open the archived board first.

Once you've re-opened the board, you should be able to

1. Click "Options"
2. Click "Archived Items"

[image: Archived Items]